# What are the excel uses of various SharedItems Attributes?

Tags: c#, excel, xml, pivot-table, openxml

I've been searching quite a bit to find what something like `containsMixedTypes` is and how it is useful in creating pivot tables, but I haven't been able to find much, outside of the Microsoft type definitions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.shareditems?view=openxml-2.8.1).

What are the definitions of the following attributes?

```
<complexType name="CT_SharedItems">
    <attribute name="containsSemiMixedTypes" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="true"/>
    <attribute name="containsNonDate" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="true"/>
    <attribute name="containsDate" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
    <attribute name="containsString" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="true"/>
    <attribute name="containsBlank" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
    <attribute name="containsMixedTypes" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
    <attribute name="containsNumber" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
    <attribute name="containsInteger" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
    <attribute name="minValue" type="xsd:double" use="optional"/>
    <attribute name="maxValue" type="xsd:double" use="optional"/>
    <attribute name="minDate" type="xsd:dateTime" use="optional"/>
    <attribute name="maxDate" type="xsd:dateTime" use="optional"/>
    <attribute name="count" type="xsd:unsignedInt" use="optional"/>
    <attribute name="longText" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
</complexType>
```

Some are obvious, such as `minValue`, but others such as `longText` or `containsMixedTypes` or `containsSemiMixedTypes` I haven't been able to find much information on. Why, for example, is it useful to know whether a field is `longText` (or whatever that means?) in Excel when working with pivot tables?

Comment: Only to format the cells of the pivot table properly.

Comment: @jdweng -- could you please elaborate? How does something like `maxDate` help with formatting a cell?

Comment: maxdate is optional and is only useful to determine if a date is valid.  With excel you can have validation formulas in the cell to make sure user only inserts valid data into a cell.

Comment: @jdweng -- thanks for this. Do you know of any place where it lists what each means in detail and how it's determined. For example, what is `longText`? Is that a word with length > 100? > 1000? With more than one word? etc.